# Efficient way to do these python list comprehensions

Tags: python, iteration, variable-assignment, list-comprehension

I had this original piece of code:

```
for x in rawFile:
    line += 1
    if line%2 == 0:
        self.newList.append(x.rstrip())
        self.timeStamp.append('0')
```

Then I saw how ugly it was and wanted to get it done with list comprehensions, hence I rewrote it as:

```
self.newList = [x[1].rstrip() for x in enumerate(rawFile) if x[0]%2 == 0]
self.timeStamp = ['0' for x in self.newList[]]
```

While the second one definitely seems more 'pythonic' to me, I still dislike the fact that I actually had to perform one extra iteration. This may be a nutty question, but does anyone know of a way where I can get this comprehension done in one iteration/line, more efficiently?

Comment: IMO, there's not much wrong with the original code. It's clear and to the point. The only change I'd make would be to use `enumerate()`.

Comment: @NPE: Yea, I know... I'm just trying to get used to python style of coding, I have been learning it as a pet project, so I figured: "do comprehensions when you can."

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/ -- this applies as much to code written in Python as to the language itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.newList, self.timeStamp = zip(*((x.rstrip(), '0') for i, x in enumerate(rawFile) if i%2==0))
```

Can't say anything about efficiency, but it *is* a one liner.

Comment: hmmm, nice zipping a list of tuples, but what is the `*` doing there?

Comment: @eazar001 it makes the `zip` output two separate lists, instead of a bunch of two element tuples. It's essentially a *transpose* function.

Comment: Very nice... Python never ceases to amaze me, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import islice
self.newList = [x.rstrip() for x in islice(rawFile, 1, None, 2)]
self.timestamp = ['0'] * len(self.newlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking for something more Pythonic, here is my suggestion:

```
for lineno, line in enumerate(rawFile):
    if lineno % 2 == 0:
        self.newList.append(line.rstrip())
        self.timeStamp.append('0')
```

Note that I've deliberately not used list comprehensions. Great as they are, I don't think they are of much help in this particular instance.

Comment: Thanks, although your answer didn't exactly meet the question, you are right... this is the most 'Pythonic', and efficient. I also ended up using your solution in my final script too. [=